# cause.getConstraintName() returning a weird string instead of actual constraint name

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-jpa

I have a column set to as `unique = true`.

Here is the code of my entity -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints=[UniqueConstraint(name = "userName", columnNames=["user_name"])])
class UserEntity(@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
                 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                 var id: Long = 0,
                 @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
                 @field:NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a user name")
                 var userName: String?)
```

Now when there is a `DataIntegrityViolationException` or `ConstraintViolationException` due to attempt to insert a duplicate `user_name` I try to extract the exact name of constraint name like this -

`val failConstraint = (ex.cause as ConstraintViolationException).constraintName`

However, instead of proper constraint name, I get a weird string - "uk_k8s0f4n7n77w1a16yhua69ony"

The detailed message is this -

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
> "uk_k8s0f4n7n77w1a16yhua69ony"\n  Detail: Key (user_name)=(krtkush)
> already exists.

I'm roughly following this answer - [Identify constraint name that trigger DataIntegrityViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462829/identify-constraint-name-that-trigger-dataintegrityviolationexception)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you drop your database and recreate the tables via hibernate after you added `uniqueConstraints=[UniqueConstraint`? Otherwise the old constraint name will be there

Comment: I did. But I did it via the GUI tool I'm using and not via hibernate.

Comment: Turns out I needed to invalidate my cache and restart my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to invalidate my IDE's cache and restart it for it to work. Nothing wrong with the code.